# Override default event listeners in Dropzone.js

Tags: dropzone.js

How do I override the default event listeners, such as `this.on('addedfile')` for `Dropzone.js`?

I am attempting to create my own template without the filename, but when I remove `<div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>` and add a file, it give me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null`.

Answer (score 3):

You override it by specifying it in your options:

```
new Dropzone("#myDropzone", {
    addedfile: function (file) {...}
}
```

If you do this you have to make sure that your implementation adds a previewElement to the file, otherwise you will get errors on other events.

I would recommend looking at the source for how the element is used. The textContent is set [on line 284](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/ff1d2dbdde0812a8c758a59f8cb4dcd616f61dad/src/dropzone.coffee#L284) of the coffeescript source (in javascript [here](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/ff1d2dbdde0812a8c758a59f8cb4dcd616f61dad/downloads/dropzone.js#L538)).

For your usecase, it should work to just copy the "addedfile" function from the source, remove that line, and then use it in your options.